# Is it possible to generate vcards 2.1 that get arroung the Thunderbird linebreaks bug?

Tags: vcf-vcard, thunderbird, quoted-printable

Without breaking the compatibility of spec-compliant softwares of course!

The link to the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589332

In fields encoded as Quoted printable, Thunderbird add an extra space on each line-break.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding one whitespace character (a space or a tab) to the beginning of each folded line.  This is what you are supposed to do to each folded line, according to the vCard version 2.1 specification.

Maybe Thunderbird is assuming that the first character of each line is whitespace, so it ignores it (whether it's *actually* whitespace or not)

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;LANGUAGE=en-nz:LastName;FirstName
FN:FirstName LastName
NOTE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=0D=0A=
 D.O.B. 13.12.41 =0D=0A=
 =0D=0A=
 24.10.05  Rang and had a lovely chat. I am sending her one of the new sheet=
 s with the piccies on.She is getting a new wig soon but is wanting to wait =
 for the new products to be up and running.  I will e-mail her once these ar=
 e all sorted.
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Yes, it does the tricks, sorry, I should have be more specific in my question : the objective is not to loose compatibility with other softwares ;) But you deserve a +1 !